# Jquery event on wrapped input radio override 'checked' event

Tags: jquery, events, radio-button, click

I want to **check and uncheck** (toggle) the radio when "td" is click but preserving the default input event

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
          <input type='radio'>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

My code attempts:

Try 1:
http://jsfiddle.net/UJXRu/

Try 2:
http://jsfiddle.net/UJXRu/1/

Try 3:
http://jsfiddle.net/UJXRu/2/

Preview:

```
$("td").click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is("input")) {
        var bool = !$(this).children("input").is(':checked');
        $(this).children("input").attr("checked", bool)
    }
    else{
        var bool2 = !$(e.target).is(':checked');
        $(e.target).attr('checked',bool2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't really understand what you're trying to achieve. You want to check the radio button when you click the td or the radio button? Can you please explain what you want to happen when you click the td, and when you click the radio button? Thanks.

Comment: i want to check radio button when I click both td or the radio button

Comment: Do you want a radio button to behave like a checkbox?

Comment: Hmmmm, right, this is a checkbox behavior.. Ok, forget the question. my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out..

```
$("td").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.type !== 'radio') {
        $(this).find(":radio").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/UJXRu/4/).

If you want to make the td and radio button toggle the radio checked property you could do something like this:

```
$("td").toggle(function() {
    $(this).children(":radio").attr("checked", true);
}, function() {
    $(this).children(":radio").attr("checked", false);
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/bCDr4/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call the default click event on the input tag:

```
$(this).children("input").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your comment:

"i want to check radio button when I click both td or the radio button"

Should be as simple as:

```
$("td").click(function(e) {
    $(this).find("input").attr("checked", true);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lukemartin/UJXRu/3/

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't treat radio buttons as check-boxes (Users really don't like that) and attempts to provide a slightly more realistic scenario.

```
$("tr.myRow").click(function(e) {
    // dont override the radio inputs default
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("childRadio") || e.target.tagName == 'LABEL')
        return;

    // find the child radio, and if it's not checked, check it.
    var $childRadio = $("input.childRadio", $(this));
    if (!$childRadio.attr('checked')) {
        $childRadio.attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
});
```

I've gone to the trouble of adding labels, and have used the name property so that the radio buttons are grouped (which is the reason to have a radio buttons). So this keeps as much default behavior as possible, and is just augmenting clicks to select a specific child radio button.

The html sample is below.

```
<tr class="myRow">  
    <td>
        <div>Some Content</div>
        <div>
            <label for="radio1">Radio 1 Label</label>
            <input type='radio' id="radio1" class="childRadio" checked="checked" name="Group1">
        </div>
        <div>More Content</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="myRow">
    <td>
        <div>
            <label for="radio2">Radio 2 Label</label> 
            <input type='radio' id="radio2" class="childRadio" name="Group1">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```